# My Excel file of CSV data from Google Apps Script doesn't mirror my Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script that passes information from a Google Spreadsheet, compiles it into a CSV file and emails that file.

**My problem:** The CSV file on my Excel file looks very different that of my Google Spreadsheet (Dead link).

This is what my Excel file looks like, pasted into another Google Spreadsheet.
[image: screenshot]

The code I am using is below:

```
function myFunction() { 

//get active sheet, the last row where data has been entered, define the range and use                  that range to get the values (called data)
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,91);
var data = range.getValues();

//define a string called csv
var csv = "";
//run for loop through the data and join the values together separated by a comma
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    csv += data[i].join(",") + "\r\n";

}
var csvFiles = [{fileName:"example.csv", content:csv}];
MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getUser().getEmail(), "New Journey Information", "",    {attachments: csvFiles}); 
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Try "\n" instead of "\r\n"; try pre-creating an Excel spreadsheet with enough columns - seems it's wrapping around

Comment: Thanks for your input. I gave that a go and unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: I know you haven't look in for a long time, but your question now contains a link to a spreadsheet that requires permission to access... and probably doesn't contain the problem anymore anyway. Can you describe the problem, so this can help other users?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that individual cells' data is atomic. For instance, what you see as a time on the sheet contains a Date object when read by your script, then when that's written to a CSV it may be converted to a date & time string with commas, depending on your locale. (Jan 4, 2013  14:34 for example.) To be safe with punctuation that may be interpreted as delimiters by Excel, you should enclose each element with quotes.

No need to modify your code, as this problem has been solved in one of the examples provided in the [Docslist Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section3). So an easy solution is to replace your code.

Change the first bit of the provided `saveAsCSV()` as follows, and it will operate either with user input or by passing a filename as a parameter.

```
function saveAsCSV(filename) {
  // Prompts the user for the file name, if filename parameter not provided
  fileName = filename || Browser.inputBox("Save CSV file as (e.g. myCSVFile):");
  ...
```